# For what values of $a$ does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+n^3)^a}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For what values of a does the series converge:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+n^3)^a}$

?

Following is my thought process:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+n^3)^a}$ =  $\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{(n+n^3)^a}$  = $\frac{1}{(1+1^3)^a} + \frac{1}{(2+2^3)^a+\frac{1}{(3+3^3)^a}}....$

So I'm thinking as long as $a \ge 1$ it should converge - but I'm not sure.

Comment: @MichaelBurr But we all know the ratio test fails for p-series like series....

Answer (score 4):

As often, equivalents are the shortest way: the general term is
$$\frac{1}{(n+n^3)^a}\sim_\infty\frac{1}{n^{3a}},$$
and the latter converges if and only if $3a>1$, i.e. $\; a>\dfrac13$.

Answer (score 3):

The denominator is
$d_n
=(n^3+n)^a
=n^{3a}(1+n^{-2})^a
$.

$d_n > n^{3a}$
so the sum converges
when $3a > 1$
or $a > \frac13$.

$d_n < 2^an^{3a}$
so the sum diverges
when $3a \le 1$
or $a \le \frac13$.

Answer (score 0):

As per the term test, we already know that $a>0$.  From there, we recognize the comparison test:

$$\frac1{(n^3+n^3)^a}<\frac1{(n+n^3)^a}<\frac1{(0+n^3)^a}$$

which gives us the p-series.

Comment: Perhaps one could use $n^3<n+n^3<2n^3$ to get a tighter bound.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I repeat the last comment.  (>.<)  And thank you for everything XD